# getting error from devise "User does not respond to 'devise' method" when running "rails generate devise:install"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm getting error from devise "User does not respond to 'devise' method" when running "rails generate devise:install".  Ideas re how to resolve?

In fact also get this error when trying to run "rails generate devise:install" I just noted.

Notes:

```
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:testapp greg$ rails generate devise:install
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/devise-2.0.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:406:in `raise_no_devise_method_error!': User does not respond to 'devise' method. This usually means you haven't loaded your ORM file or it's being loaded too late. To fix it, be sure to require 'devise/orm/YOUR_ORM' inside 'config/initializers/devise.rb' or before your application definition in 'config/application.rb' (RuntimeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/devise-2.0.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `devise_for'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/devise-2.0.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:203:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/devise-2.0.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:203:in `devise_for'
    from /Users/greg/source_rails/testapp/config/routes.rb:2
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:272:in `instance_exec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:272:in `eval_block'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:249:in `draw'
```

and

```
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:testapp greg$ ruby -v 
**ruby 1.8.7** (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]

Gregs-MacBook-Pro:testapp greg$ rails -v
**Rails 3.2.1**

Gregs-MacBook-Pro:testapp greg$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.1)
actionpack (3.2.1)
activemodel (3.2.1)
activerecord (3.2.1)
activeresource (3.2.1)
activesupport (3.2.1)
addressable (2.2.6)
arel (3.0.0)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.22)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
devise (2.0.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.3.0)
faraday (0.7.6)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
journey (1.0.1)
jquery-rails (2.0.0)
json (1.6.5)
mail (2.4.1)
mime-types (1.17.2)
multi_json (1.0.4)
multipart-post (1.1.4)
mysql (2.8.1)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
oauth (0.4.5)
oauth-plugin (0.4.0.rc2)
oauth2 (0.5.2)
orm_adapter (0.0.6)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.1)
railties (3.2.1)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
rubygems-update (1.8.15)
sass (3.1.15, 3.1.14)
sass-rails (3.2.4)
sprockets (2.1.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.5)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.31)
uglifier (1.2.3)
warden (1.1.0)
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It sounds like you already have the devise method being called in your User model.  Perhaps you already ran `rails g devise User` ?

Comment that out, and comment out the `devise_for :users` line in your routes file, if that is  in there.

Comment: tks - that seemed to fix it - what was the problem? - did I issue the commands in the wrong order and somehow things got stuffed up?  I'll have to uncomment the lines again now I assume?  (the commands I meant above were: "rails generate devise:install", "rails generate devise User", and "rake db:migrate".

Comment: @greg  - running `rails g devise:install` puts an initializer for devise in the file `config/initializers/devise.rb`.  That's what loads all the devise methods so your application can use them.  If you run `rails g devise User` before that initializer is in place, then your User model contains calls to methods that the application doesn't know about.  So whenever you run any rails commands it'll fail because of... well, the error you were getting.  It would also have failed if you tried to run `rails server` or `rails c`, or whatever.

Comment: @greg Yes you just ran the commands in the wrong order. First run "rails generate devise:install".

Comment: I get the same problem if I run `rails g devise User` first. If I comment out `devise_for :users` in my routes file then I can successfully run `rake db:migrate`... I was wondering if I leave my `devise_for :users` permanently commented out or can I uncomment it?

Comment: @leggooo you can uncomment it once you have run the migrations.

Answer (score 5):

Completing a tutorial for rails & these answers didn't work for me, but after some searching found a solution. Hope this helps anyone else who's new and running into this issue.

1. Go to: **config/routes.rb** file
2. Comment out the line `devise_for :installs` (put a hash tag in front)
3. Go to your Ruby terminal and re-enter: `rails generate devise:install`

Now Devise should install properly & subsequent errors should be gone.

[Source](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/devise-not-installing)

Answer (score 1):

For people that arrived here due to the following error:

> User does not respond to 'devise' method. This usually means you
>   haven't loaded your ORM file or it's being loaded too late. To fix it,
>   be sure to require 'devise/orm/YOUR_ORM' inside
>   'config/initializers/devise.rb' or before your application definition
>   in 'config/application.rb' (RuntimeError)

but you already have your ORM initialized properly, it may be gem related. I was getting the same problem on an old app and it was due to an incompatibility with the `active_reload` gem. `gem active_reload` is not compatible with Rails 3.2 and should be removed. [active_reload](https://github.com/paneq/active_reload) has been incorporated into Rails 3.2, so it's safe to remove.

I got the solution from here: http://anlek.com/2012/02/user-does-not-respond-to-devise-method/

Answer (score 0):

i had this same problem. however for me it was caused by a conflict with the active_reload gem. once i removed that all was well.  i got the tip from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1597

Comment: i thought i did. i said it was the active reload gem