# User does not respond to 'devise' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and when trying to run a migration or anything that involves initializing this app like running it on the local server I get this error and the process is aborted.

`User does not respond to 'devise' method. This usually means you haven't loaded your ORM file or it's being loaded too late. To fix it, be sure to require 'devise/orm/YOUR_ORM' inside 'config/initializers/devise.rb' or before your application definition in 'config/application.rb'`

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

The app is not mine, I cloned it from a repository and I'm working on it as an intern.  I noticed that the name of the app is actually incorrect in all the config files.  They've used the same name of a separate app I work on, but they've used it consistently so I'm not sure that should cause a problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting error from devise "User does not respond to 'devise' method" when running "rails generate devise:install"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247334/getting-error-from-devise-user-does-not-respond-to-devise-method-when-runnin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this question

[getting error from devise "User does not respond to 'devise' method" when running "rails generate devise:install"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247334/getting-error-from-devise-user-does-not-respond-to-devise-method-when-runnin)

1st answer will probably solve your problem.