# Rails: User does not respond to 'devise' method” when running “rails generate devise:install"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, devise

I have been working on this issue for hours now and haven't seemed to find anything exactly like this on StackOverflow.

```
   C:\Sites\isawyou>rake db:migrate
    rake aborted!
    User does not respond to 'devise' method. This usually means you haven't loaded
    your ORM file or it's being loaded too late. To fix it, be sure to require 'devi
    se/orm/YOUR_ORM' inside 'config/initializers/devise.rb' or before your applicati
    on definition in 'config/application.rb'
    C:/Sites/isawyou/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    C:/Sites/isawyou/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    C:2:in `rescue in execute_if_updated'
    C:in `execute_if_updated'
    C:/Sites/isawyou/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Issue: Everytime I try to migrate I get this error. However, I do not have a devise.rb file installed so am not sure how to fix this..

Attempts to solve: tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9247357/2234019) however that didn't let me populate the correct rake routes I needed (ie: new user sessions, create new user, etc..)

Tried redoing the order of commands (as shown below).. But that didn't work either.. I always get stuck at the "rake db:migrate" portion..

```
$ rails d devise User
$ rails generate devise:install (you may have to override previous files)
$ rails generate devise User
$ rake db:drop
$ rake db:create
$ rake db:migrate
$ rake routes
```

Thank you in advance if you know the fix!!

Comment: What are the contents of these files. `config/initializers/devise.rb` and `config/application.rb`

Comment: If there has been a previous failed attempt there may be a migration file in the `db/migrate` directory that is causing this problem.  Might be worth checking to see what's there

Comment: What is that? `$ rails d devise User`

Comment: @Althaf There is no `config/initializers/devise.rb` but a `config/application.rb` exists. 
@muttonlamb: yes, there is a migration file there. Is there something specific I should do with it?

Comment: @Althaf-- My application.rb file looks like this:
`require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
if defined?(Bundler)
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
end
module Isawyou
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
  end
end`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have devise generator previously run unsuccessfully. Backtrace gives a clue that error happens within config/routes.rb line 2. I guess there is a following line of code, setting up devise routes

```
devise_for :users
```

But your users model doesn't have devise modules setup. There should be something like

```
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
# :timeoutable  and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

If this line is present it means that devise is improperly installed.

Also there is a chance that you have another class or module "User" within ActiveSupport::Dependencies autoloader paths and when devise_for :users line requires User class this class/module loaded first, whereas your real User module is not loaded. The "invalid" user module/class is not ActiveRecord descendant, so devise AR hook is not installed to it, so it doesn't have #devise method. So make sure you don't have any other classes/modules named User

Comment: Hello, you are correct, my user.rb model has the line 
`devise :database_authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable`
With this in mind, would you know how to fix this?
Thank you!